# Hive-metastore not finding Hadoop Datanode

Tags: docker, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have an Hadoop cluster with one namenode and one datanode instantiated with docker compose. In addition I am trying to launch Hive but the Hive-metastore seems not to find my datanode even if this one is up and running, infact checking the log it shows:

```
namenode:9870 is available.
check for datanode:9871...
datanode:9871 is not available yet
try in 5s once again ...
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
#HADOOP
  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: namenode
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "9870"
      - "54310"
      - "9000"
    ports:
      - 9870:9870
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - ./data/hadoop_data/:/hadoop_data
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=test
      - CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:9000
      - CORE_CONF_hadoop_http_staticuser_user=root
      - CORE_CONF_hadoop_proxyuser_hue_hosts=*
      - CORE_CONF_hadoop_proxyuser_hue_groups=*
      - CORE_CONF_io_compression_codecs=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec

      - HDFS_CONF_dfs_webhdfs_enabled=true
      - HDFS_CONF_dfs_permissions_enabled=false
      - HDFS_CONF_dfs_namenode_datanode_registration_ip___hostname___check=false
      - HDFS_CONF_dfs_safemode_threshold_pct=0

  datanode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: datanode
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "9871"
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870"
    ports:
      - "9871:9871"
    env_file:
      - hive.env

hive-server:
    image: bde2020/hive:2.3.2-postgresql-metastore
    container_name: hive-server
    volumes:
      - ./employee:/employee
    env_file:
      - hive.env
    environment:
      HIVE_CORE_CONF_javax_jdo_option_ConnectionURL: "jdbc:postgresql://hive-metastore/metastore"
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "hive-metastore:9083"
    depends_on:
      - hive-metastore
    ports:
      - "10000:10000"

  hive-metastore:
    image: bde2020/hive:2.3.2-postgresql-metastore
    container_name: hive-metastore
    env_file:
      - hive.env
    command: /opt/hive/bin/hive --service metastore
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870 datanode:9871 hive-metastore-postgresql:5432"
    depends_on:
      - hive-metastore-postgresql
    ports:
      - "9083:9083"

  hive-metastore-postgresql:
    image: bde2020/hive-metastore-postgresql:2.3.0
    container_name: hive-metastore-postgresql
    volumes:
      - ./metastore-postgresql/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    depends_on:
      - datanode
```

Comment: And what do the logs of the datanode look like? The metastore shouldn't need a datanode. If you're referring to the bottom service, that's a just a Postgres database and doesn't require outgoing Hadoop communication, so doesn't depend on anything. Besides, it's missing `env_file` definition if you did want to set up variables for it like the others